# Windows Phone 7 Toolkit: How to reload the data in the Loopingselector control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the LoopingSelector to show a series of timestamps. As time progresses, I'd like to update the timestamps in the looping selector.

I have a class that implements the `ILoopingSelectorDataSource` interface, but I can't figure out how to force the data to reload while the control is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claus is partially correct, there doesn't seem to be a way to use binding to update the control, but in code behind, calling

`LoopingSelector.DataSource = new MyLoopingSelectorDataSource() 
// your implementation of the ILoopingSelectorDataSource interface`

will cause the control to reload data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't. The control doesn't update the currently rendered controls. You would have to rewrite the control to fit your purpose.

While you can easily make it calculate the time relatively to a given point upon the call to GetNext() or GetPrevious(), updating the elements already on the screen would require a invoke of a kind, or a constant update per second/minute or whatever fast you want them to update.